# User-specific default spawner URL on JupyterHub

Tags: jupyter, jupyter-lab, jupyterhub

I recently set up JupyterLab on our university server and will now let other users access the hub. Is there a possibility to configure, which is the default Jupyter application (**notebook**, **lab**, **voila** etc.) by user?

In jupyterhub_config.py which is in /etc/jupyter/, there is only a global option which URL to use as default:

```
c.Spawner.default_url = '/lab'
```

How can I differentiate the behaviour by user? Is it possible to only allow certain users the use of **lab** and **notebook** and limit other users to using **voila**?